# Boundary of a submanifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, manifolds-with-boundary, submanifold

Let be $M$ a smooth manifold with boundary and $N \subset M$ a submanifold with boundary, such $N$ is a closed subset of $M$ in the topological sense. Denote $\partial N$ be the boundary of $N$ as a manifold, and $\mathring{N}=\overline{N}-Int(N)$ the boundary of $N$ in the topological sense. Is it true

$\mathring{N}=N$ if $dim(N)<dim(M)$ $\hspace{5 mm}$ and $\hspace{5 mm}$
$\mathring{N}=\partial N$ if $dim(N)=dim(M)$ ?

Does the result change if $N$ and $M$ are non smooth, but $C^k$ manifolds with some $k\in \mathbb{N}_0 $?

Comment: This is highly confusing notation, as most people use $\mathring N$ for the interior of $N$. But, yes, what you say seems correct.

Comment: The first claim is true (even  in the category of topological manifolds), the second claim is false even if dimension of M equals 1.

Comment: Thanks, for the answers. Could you give me a counterexample for the falseness of the second statement, @MoisheCohen ?

Comment: @Diego: $M=[0,1]=N$.